# Replacing an Objective-C iOS app with a brand new Swift app while keeping values from NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store-connect, nsuserdefaults

I have a general question when it comes to replacing an old application with a brand new one. The old application is several years old and written in Objective-C and I am developing an update from scratch in Swift.

I am wondering how to preserve a variable from the old app called "`email_preference`" which is stored in `NSUserDefaults`. How do I access the variable when the update is complete, and how do I test that I get the variable correctly (I feel like I have to do it correctly the first time or the value will be lost)?

These are the mentions I have found in the old code:

```
//Saves the email
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:self.email.text forKey:@"email_preference"];

//Gets the email
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *email = [defaults objectForKey:@"email_prefe
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the "new" app has the same bundle identifier as the "old" one, you can get the saved email just like this:

```
let email = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "email_preference")
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I was expecting as much, but I wanted to be sure just in case :)